# How to change Django's default label name of comment form into Chinese?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using Django's built-in comments app. But I have met one problem.

The default label for the comments form is English(e.g. "Name","Email Address"), but I'd like to change them into Chinese. So I went to `site-packages/django/contrib/comments/forms.py` and amend them as below:

```
name          = forms.CharField(label=_("姓名 Name"), max_length=50)
email         = forms.EmailField(label=_("邮箱 Email"))
url           = forms.URLField(label=_("网站 URL"), required=False)
comment       = forms.CharField(label=_("评论 Comment"), widget=forms.Textarea,
                               max_length=COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH)
```

But it failed when I runserver again, it says

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe5' in file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/comments/forms.py on line 98, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

So I went to http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html and Add "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" in the head of forms.py file. To be joy, I can run the server. But when I went to the comment Page, the comment form disappeared!

Can anybody tell me what's going on? And how to repair it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's `comments` app [is already translated to Chinese](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.po), you don't need to do that yourself.

You will just need to [enable internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/deployment/) in your django configuration:

```
USE_I18N = True

LANGUAGES = (
  ('zh_CN', 'Chinese'),
)
```

You can roll back all the changes you made to the `django/contrib/comments/forms.py` file.